# how to add new node to database with treelist?

Tags: c#, treeview, devexpress

I have a `devexpress` treelist with some nodes and roots. I am trying to add new nodes or roots to my treelist and of course to add it to my database. When I click a root, I would like to add a node to that root. Can somebody help me? Any ideas?

My code:

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM YETKILENDIR_OZELLIKLER", CommandType.Text);
    treeList1.DataSource = cnn.GetData(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                 private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                    DbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM YETKILENDIR_OZELLIKLER", CommandType.Text);
                    Dataset Ds= cnn.GetData(cmd);
                    treeList1.Nodes.Clear();
                    if (Ds != null) {
                    if (Ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count > 0) {
                        TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
                        foreach (DataRow dr in Ds.Tables(0).Rows) {
                            tNode = new TreeNode();
                            fl = dr("FirstLevel");
                            tNode.Text = fl;
                            treeList1.Nodes.Add(tNode);
                        }
                        treeList1.ExpandAll();
                    }
                }
```